# Why am I getting a syntax error in this code?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I'm working on a physics project and now I keep getting this syntax error that I can't figure out.

```
if caixa.moving: #se a caixa mexe, tudo mexe
    if peso.pos.y - peso.size.y/2 >0: #se o peso ainda não chegou ao chão
        #Equacoes
        IntensidadeAceleracao = (peso.mass * 9.8 - mag (forcaAtritoCineticoCaixa)/(peso.mass + caixa.mass)
        peso.acceleration = IntensidadeAceleracao * vector(0,-1,0)
        caixa.acceleration = IntensidadeAceleracao * vector(1,0,0)
```

The line peso.acceleration gets a syntax error in the peso part

Comment: **Alert:** Irony in title.

Comment: Both *read* and then *post* the actual error message. (Anyway, you're missing a `)`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on line 4. You didn't close the parentheses, so Python tries to include the next line as part of the previous. The syntax error occurs when that's not possible

```
IntensidadeAceleracao = (peso.mass * 9.8 - mag (forcaAtritoCineticoCaixa)/(peso.mass + caixa.mass)
                                               (------------------------) (----------------------)
                        (----------------- -- -- - -  -     -                                     ?
```

In cases like this, I wish Python would be a bit more explicit with its error messages. Something like:

```
Syntax Error in implicit line continuation inside parentheses
```

(After all, we all forget to close parentheses sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss a ")" in the line above it